# Caixa com cor diferentes em cada linha - HTML 5 / CSS3

Tags: html, css

Bom Dia,

---

Estou recém começando com HTML e CSS3 e estou fazendo desafio de construir uma pequena página como exemplo, porém estou batendo batendo cabeça com a caixa que fica ao final da página, abaixo vou deixar uma imagem de como teria que ficar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porém o resultado que consegui chegar foi esse abaixo, sei que não está certo, poderia me dar uma dica, um exemplo?**

```css
.caixa{
    background-color:rgb(39, 194, 39);
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(39, 194, 39);
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.caixa2{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-decoration: underline;

}
```

```html
    <h3 class="caixa">Quer aprender mais?
        <p class="caixa"> Outro assunto curioso em relação ao Android é que cada versão sempre foi nomeada em homenagem a um doce, em ordem alfabética a partir da versão 1.5 até a 9.0.
            <ul class="caixa2"  style="color: black;">
                <div style="page-break-after: 0px;">
                <li type="disc">1.5 Cupcake</li>
                <li type="disc">1.6 Donut</li>
                <li type="disc">3.0 - Eclair</li>
                <li type="disc">2.2 - Froyo</li>
                <li type="disc">2.3 - Gingerbread</li>
                <li type="disc">3.0 - Honeycomb</li>
                <li type="disc">4.0 - Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
                </div> 
                <div style="page-break-after: 0px;">
                <li type="disc">4.1 - Jelly Bean</li>
                <li type="disc">4.4 - KitKat</li>
                <li type="disc">5.0 - Lolipop</li>
                <li type="disc">6.0 - Marshmallow</li>
                <li type="disc">7.0 - Nougat</li>
                <li type="disc">8.0 - Oreo</li>
                <li type="disc">9.0 - Pie</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <p>Infelizmente, o Android Q não existiu, pois o Google resolveu pôr fim a essa divertida prática e começou a usar numerações, o que deu origem ao Android 10.</p>
        <p>Acesse aqui o site <a href="https://www.android.com/intl/pt-BR_br/history/">Android History</a> para conhecer a sequência das versões "adocicadas" e o que cada uma trouxe para o sistema Android.</p>
        </h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há alguns erros no código, mas simples de solucionar, vou listar alguns, como as tags h3 e p estão fechando no final, englobando ou outros elementos.
No seu exemplo seria melhor usar uma tabela, para representar da forma que você quer, fiz um código básico de exemplo pra você entender e partir dai modificar e fazer suas alterações

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .caixa {
      margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
      background-color: rgb(39, 194, 39);
      border-width: 10px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: rgb(39, 194, 39);
      color: white;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }

    .caixa2 {
      margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: greenyellow;
      border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
      border-width: 10px;
    }

    td>span {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

O css fiz dessa forma para exemplificar, o * zera todas as margens e espaçamentos internos (padding)

```
<div class="caixa">
    <h3>Quer aprender mais?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="caixa2">
    <p> Outro assunto curioso em relação ao Android é que cada versão sempre foi nomeada em homenagem a um doce, em ordem alfabética a partir da versão 1.5 até a 9.0.</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 1.5 - <span>Cupcake</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 4.1 - <span>Jelly Bean</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 1.6 - <span>Donut</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 4.4 - <span>KitKat</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 3.0 - <span>Eclair</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 5.0 - <span>Lolipop</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 2.2 - <span>Froyo</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 6.0 - <span>Marshmallow</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 2.3 - <span>Gingerbread</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 7.0 - <span>Nougat</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 3.0 - <span>Honeycomb</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 8.0 - <span>Oreo</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#10004 4.0 - <span>Ice Cream Sandwich</span></td>
        <td>&#10004 9.0 - <span>Pie</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Infelizmente, o Android Q não existiu, pois o Google resolveu pôr fim a essa divertida prática e começou a usar numerações, o que deu origem ao Android 10.</p>
    <br>
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Acesse aqui o site <a href="https://www.android.com/intl/pt-BR_br/history/">Android History</a> para conhecer a sequência das versões "adocicadas" e o que cada uma trouxe para o sistema Android.</p>
  </div>
```

e o html dessa forma, como eu havia citado, há representação e alguns caracteres especiais como &#10004 e o espaçamento &nbsp.
Espero ter te ajudado, esse é um exemplo bem básico para você entender, continue estudando que você consegue ir longe.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que talvez seja melhor para leitura/SEO se você colocar a Tag `h3` somente para o cabeçalho e usar uma `div` para encapsular as demais:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="caixa">
      <h3 class="cabecalho-caixa">Quer aprender mais?</h3>
  <div class="content">
  <p>Outro assunto curioso em relação ao Android é que cada versão sempre foi nomeada em homenagem a um doce, em ordem alfabética a partir da versão 1.5 até a 9.</p>
.
.
.
```

Para dispor a lista em 2 colunas, basta usar a propriedade css `columns`:

```
ul {
  columns: 2;
}
```

### Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, vou começar a entender melhor as divs, ainda sei pouco sobre elas. Sobre as colunas nas listas também desconhecia sobre isso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link, ele pode te ajudar: [HTML <div> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.ASP)

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, valiosas dicas

Answer (score 0):

Por hora consegui resolver adicionando várias caixas e juntando todas, sei que não seria o ideal, mas o layout ficou certo.

```css
.caixa{
    background-color:#2FA866;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;

}

.caixa2{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #C5EBD6;
    columns: 2;
    
}

.caixa3{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #C5EBD6;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -16px
}

.caixa4{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #C5EBD6;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="caixa">Quer aprender mais?</h3>
        <p class="caixa2" style=" columns: 1;"> Outro assunto curioso em relação ao Android é que cada versão sempre foi nomeada em homenagem a um doce, em ordem alfabética a partir da versão 1.5 até a 9.0.
            <br>
            <br>
            <ul class="caixa2" style="text-decoration: underline;">
                <div>
                <li>✓ 1.5 Cupcake</li>
                <li>✓ 1.6 Donut</li>
                <li>✓ 3.0 - Eclair</li>
                <li>✓ 2.2 - Froyo</li>
                <li>✓ 2.3 - Gingerbread</li>
                <li>✓ .0 - Honeycomb</li>
                <li>✓ 4.0 - Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
                </div> 
                <div>
                <li>✓ 4.1 - Jelly Bean</li>
                <li>✓ 4.4 - KitKat</li>
                <li>✓ 5.0 - Lolipop</li>
                <li>✓ 6.0 - Marshmallow</li>
                <li>✓ 7.0 - Nougat</li>
                <li>✓ 8.0 - Oreo</li>
                <li>✓ 9.0 - Pie</li>
                <br>
                <br>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <p class="caixa3">Infelizmente, o Android Q não existiu, pois o Google resolveu pôr fim a essa divertida prática e começou a usar numerações, o que deu origem ao Android 10.
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
        <p class="caixa4">Acesse aqui o site Android History para conhecer a sequência das versões "adocicadas" e o que cada uma trouxe para o sistema Android.
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
```